# Mamp - MySql doesn't start

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

Today i'm trying to start server on mamp and just apache runs.
Yesterday both work well.

After search i try kill process but returns me that any mysql process exists.

In log file i have this error:

```
170515 11:57:53 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
170515 11:57:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56
2017-05-15 11:57:56 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-05-15 11:57:56 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-05-15 11:57:56 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.34) starting as process 9466 ...
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 108418575 and 108418575 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 108675003 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-05-15 11:57:56 9466 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace atena/wp_comments uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./atena/wp_comments.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
2017-05-15 11:57:56 7fffb92813c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170515 11:57:56 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

After search i saw people speak about `my.cnf` file but i don't have this file...

How can i solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to change your tables types? this error `Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd` means that it could not open the file either it doesn't exist or it is corrupted check it.

Comment: How can i do that @JorgeCampos ?
what is the location of innodb_index_stats.ibd

Comment: I go to '/mysql/innodb_index_stats.idb' and open the file with atom with '?' character. What i have to do now? @JorgeCampos

Comment: If the file is in the location (mysql_data_folder) it means that it is corrupted, therefore you will need to reinstall that database.

Comment: How? if i don't have access to database? @JorgeCampos
And i have a lot of databases.

Comment: If you have access to the mysql, you can drop the database.

Comment: but the problem is that. I don't have access to databases because i cannot start mysql @JorgeCampos

Comment: Then you need to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete ib_logfileN in Mamp/db/mysql56. Had the same issue and its working. Maybe you'll need also to delete ibdataN. You can copy the folder to have a backup.